# How to change a specific value for all firebase keys

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a flutter application. How do I **retrieve** and **change** the "Weight" value for all the keys in my Firebase database even if I do not know the names of all the keys?

[image]

Comment: Assuming you want to write a front-end app in `Flutter`, based on the tag? You can use the `firebase_database` plug-in and start with their examples: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database

Comment: You will have to write code to query the entire UserData node, iterate its children, find the data you're looking for in each one, then update each child value individually.  This is not just one simple command to do all this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use,

```
_ref!.child("childName").update({'MapValue': 'Value'});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me to change one specific value from a collection. I apply this in flutter in a onTap button. I hope it will work any onPressed or setOnClieckListener.

```
   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').get().then((snapshot) {
       for (DocumentSnapshot ds in snapshot.docs) {
            ds.reference.update({
                                  'gender': "Male"
                            });
        }
     });
```